# insert XML Result with cURL to SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, api, curl

i want add result to DB SQL :)

result is xml from api link want insert to SQL table : localhost -> Database: travel » Table: countries,

and want know how can parse to html table too

i use many method but dont work for me

thanks

```
<?php
    $request='<Request>
    <Head>
    <Username>3588130b7dbdded931357eb089ea5a30</Username>
    <Password>tP9z3434DHf4V</Password>
    <RequestType>GetCountries</RequestType>  
    </Head>  
    <Body/> 
    </Request>';
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxxxxxxx");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => $request));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $data
    ?>
```

result : 
250 country

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Response>
    <Head>
        <ServerTime>2016-07-05T05:56:42</ServerTime>
        <ServerType>Test</ServerType>
        <ResponseType>GetCountries</ResponseType>
        <ExecutionTime>0.007</ExecutionTime>
    </Head>
    <Body>
    <CountriesReturned>250</CountriesReturned>
        <Countries>
            <Country>
                <CountryCode>AF</CountryCode>
                <CountryName>Afghanistan</CountryName>
            </Country>
        </Countries>
        ....
    </Body>
</Response>
```

one method :

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456789"); //connect to server
mysql_select_db("travel", $con) or die(mysql_error()); //select database

    foreach($xml->Countries as $mess){
       $mess->Country;
           {
               $account_number= mysql_real_escape_string($mess->CountryCode);
               $main= mysql_real_escape_string($mess->CountryName);
           //insert into databse                     
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO countries (ISO_CODE, Name)
            VALUES ('$account_number', '$main')")
         or die(mysql_error());
            echo "inserted into mysql<br /><br />";
           //show updated records            
          printf ("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());  
        }
```

Comment: *i use many method but dont work for me* - show us what you tried

Comment: Can you post some of the "many methods" you've tried, please? You'll generally want to use [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse the XML, and a DB library like [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to then insert the data.